# Background Audio App crashing when Lock Screen is displayed

Tags: iphone, avaudioplayer, background-process, nszombie

I have an App that plays audio, it uses:

```
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
```

To play audio when in the background.

Pressing the wake/sleep button<sup>1</sup> of the device locks the screen and turns off the display. If the audio is left to play for approximately 8 minutes and I press either the sleep/wake or home button the app will crash.

This is very odd for several reasons:

1. The app is not being "resumed", only the display is being turned on and the lock screen is shown.
2. None on the App delegate methods are called: `-applicationWillEnterForeground:`, `-applicationDidBecomeActive:`
3. The App does not display any artwork on the lock screen via `MPNowPlayingInfoCenter`

I have enabled NSZombies and then I get a:

```
 *** -[__NSArrayM removeObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x10bf9060
```

And the backtrace looks like this (not much help!):

[image: Backtrace]

#### Console Output

This is the console output around the time of the crash.

```
Aug 29 11:37:30 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=1
Aug 29 11:37:30 unknown UserEventAgent[12] <Warning>: DEBUG: Changing screen blanked state: 0
Aug 29 11:37:30 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 255->0 (deferring until bootloaded)
Aug 29 11:37:30 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: device bootloaded
Aug 29 11:37:30 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->0
Aug 29 11:37:30 unknown myapp[19495] <Error>: *** -[__NSArrayM removeObject:]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x12158bc0
Aug 29 11:37:38 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Notice>: Posting 'com.apple.iokit.hid.displayStatus' notifyState=0
Aug 29 11:37:38 unknown SpringBoard[51] <Notice>: MultitouchHID: detection mode: 0->255
Aug 29 11:37:38 unknown UserEventAgent[12] <Warning>: DEBUG: Changing screen blanked state: 1
Aug 29 11:37:49 unknown kernel[0] <Debug>: AppleSerialMultiplexer: mux-ad(eng)::dormancySetIntervalGated: Setting dormancy interval to 0 ms with mask 0
```

Any suggestions on how to track down the issue? It looks like there are some system level calls that get sent to the app when the lock screen is shown, but I have no idea how they are triggering a `-removeObject` call or who even owns this object?

> <sup>1. At the right of the top of the iPhone sits the wake/sleep
> button. It is a thin, unobtrusive button. It takes a fair amount of
> pressure to activate it. That combined with the unobtrusiveness makes
> accidental activation less likely. It also provides good tactile
> feedback. The wake/sleep button has two primary purposes, to put the
> iPhone into sleep mode instantly and wake it from sleep mode. You can
> also press it twice to send an incoming call straight to voice mail, a
> useful function that can be accomplished just by touch.</sup>